# How to Ban an IP address automatically in ubuntu 12.04 when it sends specific packet to server?

Tags: linux, networking, ubuntu, iptables

I run a game server and someone is attacking with fake players. I want to ban him automatically in Ubuntu V P S. Any  IPtables command or program that can accomplish this task?

If it's not possible is there a way to limit the connection. 1 IP  per connection so that one IP can't connect to server with different ports at same time?

I  tried one iptables command iptables -A INPUT -p udp -m length --length 0:28 -j DROP but that failed

Comment: Please add what you have tried and the results you received.  This will assist in getting an answer.

Comment: i tried one iptables command iptables -A INPUT -p udp -m length --length 0:28 -j DROP